# tomcat6 regular task every 10 seconds

Tags: java, task, tomcat6

Does tomcat do some regular task every 10 seconds?

I notice this at my local tomcat server, but not on the remote server.

Here's JVM CPU usage:[image: CPU usage]

Noticing that there's a peak about every 10 seconds. I'm running nothing, and, what's it doing?

**UPDATE** :  here are the threads, it's true that I'm using `quartz` for scheduler task.
but they are always in status waiting.

[image: threads local host]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the [Java monitor](http://java-monitor.com/forum/welcome.php) or visualVM like tool and check that which classes are involved.Could be possible your tomcat is using Quartz.

Comment: Thanks, I update the threads status. And I'm gonna check out with the tool you mentioned.

Comment: still no idea what it is.

Comment: Could this be JMX server connection?

Comment: Thanks, I've done a test with another quite simple webApp on the tomcat server, this time, the JMX server connection takes less time on running and more time on waiting. So it's this thread which runs regularly, and how much cpu it uses depends on how complex your application is, I think.